# Karma Runner doesnt find path to ES6 module from tsconfig.json

Tags: angular, karma-runner, es6-modules

I am trying to load an external module which generated Karma Config. This module basically provides contents of karma.config.js

This is an Angular 6 project. The setup is such that my tsconfig.json looks like

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "newLine": "LF",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "test-config": [
        "dist/test-config"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The mapping of test-config points to dist/test-config. I verified that this directory exist and its contents are true.

To angular.json i say things like

```js
 "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/components/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/components/tsconfig.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/components/karma.config.ts"
          }
        },
```

My karma.config.ts loads the external es6 module as its first line.

```js
import { ExtendedKarmaConfig } from "test-config";
```

When i fire karma runner by command ng test, it fails trying to find test-config. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should move the file to a different location. '/dist' is deleted on build by cli. Plus you're telling TS to find test-config under the directory /dist/test-config.

Comment: the dist folder is actually generted by ng build. The problem is fixed when you specify the absolute path to test-config project.